# How do I join properties of objects in a list in a Django template?

Tags: django-templates

In a Django template, I can join a list of strings via

```
{{ listOfStrings | join: ", " }}
```

What if I want to join a certain property of objects in the list. For instance, what if I have a list of users and want to join their full names?

```
{{ listOfUsers.get_full_name | join: ", " }}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

afaik, you can't do that with built in template tags, and certainly not filters. What you probably want is a custom tag that does

```
return ",".join([user.get_full_name for user in listOfUsers])
```

Building custom tags: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/